# How to merge multiple EPS file to one EPS file

Tags: graphics, journal-publishing

My paper is accepted and I have to modify something.

The officer said that

> All figure parts should be included in one file, on one page. For
>   example, if Figure 1 contains three parts (a, b, c), then all of the
>   labeled parts should be combined in a single file for Figure 1.

For example, in one figure, there are 32 EPS files (4*8). Now, how to make one EPS file for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a `tabular` structure representing the combined image and compile it with the `standalone` document class:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Just for this example
\newcommand{\img}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *8{c} }
  \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img \\
  \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img \\
  \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img \\
  \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img & \img
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The above creates a 4-row, 8-column structure with images into a single output. Compile it with LaTeX > dvips to obtain a single PostScipt image (or pdfLaTeX to obtain a PDF).

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my case, there is a gap between rows. I am now trying solving this issue.

Comment: @topy: You can add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}` before the `tabular`.